# Prolog - Save List into something like an atom?

Tags: list, prolog

I made some predicate, which saves a very complex list into a variable `P`.
Let's say:

```
  pred(P) :- 
    P = [[1, a, b, c, 234],d].
```

Now I want to put this list into another predicate, let's say

```
  pred2(P, L) :-
    nth1(2, P, L).
```

My problem now is, I don't want to copy `[[1, a, b, c, 234], d]` as parameter into `P`. Is their a simple way, maybe to define an atom or another shortcut, e.g. '`test' := [[1, a, b, c, 234],d]`. and call `?- pred2('test', L)`?

Comment: If you are using SWI-Prolog and doing unit test, then see [Prolog Unit Tests](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/plunit.html%27))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple way is to *call* the predicate which you've defined:

```
   pred2(L) :-
     pred(P),    % :- P = [[1, a, b, c, 234],d].
     nth1(2, P, L).
```

This will "set" nay instantiate the logical variable `P` first, then use it to "set" `L`.

Note `P` has become an internal variable here. You don't have to set it when calling `pred2`. `pred2` will call `pred` for you, to set `P`.